# Pause multiple Vimeo embeds from multiple a tags

Tags: javascript, vimeo

So basically I have a single page website with a whole bunch of hidden Vimeo videos. I need all the videos to pause when not displayed.

So far I'm able to pause one video when clicking on a specific anchor tag, but I want to be able to pause all the videos by clicking any of the a tags.

I tried many different things, but with my limited knowledge of JavaScript, I feel I'm out of my depth.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

```
<script>
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("name");
if (name == 'newboxes') {
if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
}
else {
newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
}}}}
</script>

<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes0" style="display: block;">
<iframe id="player" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/53407474?api=1&player_id=player" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes0" style="display: none;">
<iframe id="player" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/53855813?api=1&player_id=player" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes0" style="display: none;">
<iframe id="player" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/19780095?api=1&player_id=player" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>

<a name="button" id="button1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes0');"><span></span></a>
<a name="button" id="button2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');"><span></span></a>
<a name="button" id="button3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');"><span></span></a>

<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ready(player_id) {
var player = $f(player_id);
pauseButton = document.getElementById('button1');
pauseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
player.api('pause');
});}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
$f(document.getElementById('player')).addEvent('ready', ready);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one of the things I notice right off the back is that you have multiple ID that are the same. ID's are supposed to be unique.Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef9BN/14/).

So I re-wrote your html to be like this

```
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes0" style="display: block;">
    <iframe id="player0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/53407474?api=1&player_id=player" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: none;">
    <iframe id="player1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/53855813?api=1&player_id=player" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: none;">
    <iframe id="player2" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/19780095?api=1&player_id=player" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>

<a name="button" id="button0" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes0');"><span>Button1</span></a>
<a name="button" id="button1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');"><span>Button2</span></a>
<a name="button" id="button2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');"><span>Button3</span></a>​
```

Than I updated your JavaScript to look like this

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    var newboxes = document.getElementsByName("newboxes"), x=0;

    for(var x = 0; x < newboxes.length; x++) {
        if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
            newboxes[x].style.display = 'block'; 
            var strPlayerID = newboxes[x].id.replace("newboxes", "player"); 
            var iframe = $('#'+strPlayerID)[0], player = $f(iframe);
            player.api('play');  
        } else {
            newboxes[x].style.display = 'none'; 
            var strPlayerID = newboxes[x].id.replace("newboxes", "player"); 
            var iframe = $('#'+strPlayerID)[0], player = $f(iframe);
            player.api('pause'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!